# Can't build WSO2 XACML sample project using Maven

Tags: maven, wso2, xacml

I'm trying to develop the XACML Sample for Health Care Application – 1 tutorial located [here](http://xacmlinfo.com/2012/03/06/xacml-sample-for-health-care). It states you must build the project using Maven

So I tried:

```
mvn package
```

But get the following error:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project com.medi.sample.service: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.medi:com.medi.sample.service:jar:1.0.0: Failure to find org.apache.axis2:axis2:jar:1.6.1-wso2v5 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

What's the proper way to build the project using Maven?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is based on the wrong version of the dependency axis2 with version 1.6.1-wso2v5 which couldn't be found in Maven Central. Either this means you have to configure a supplemental repository or simply the example does not work that way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have got the answer from here [1]...  :)  However you need to configure a maven repository in the pom.xml file and you need to build online...  I guess there was an issue with that pom.xml file according this [2]... seems to be it is fixed now..

[1] http://xacmlinfo.com/2012/03/06/xacml-sample-for-health-care/#comment-145
[2] http://xacmlinfo.com/2012/03/06/xacml-sample-for-health-care/#comment-150